# How to fix 'Incompatible types' error when converting String to int in Java?

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I'm teaching myself java and I came across this error. I'm trying to enter a number of a month and I have to use a switch case to return the "answer". I get the follow error:

```java
package javauebung5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type Number for name of month");
        int monthNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        monthNumber = determineNameofMonth(monthNumber);
    }

    private static String determineNameofMonth(int monthNumber) {
        switch (monthNumber) {
            case 1: return "January";

            case 2: return "February";

            case 3: return "March";

            case 4: return "April";

            case 5: return "May";

            case 6: return "June";

            case 7: return "July";

            case 8: return "August";

            case 9: return "September";

            case 10: return "October";

            case 11: return "November";

            case 12: return "December";

        }
        return "Invalid Month";
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'int'

Comment: `monthNumber` is an `int` type which cannot accept `String` type. You can declare a new `String` variable and assign the return of the `determineNameofMonth` method to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 monthNumber = determineNameofMonth(monthNumber);
```

Per its declaration and intent, determineNameofMonth returns a String. Here you attempt to assign to an integer; the error message is telling you that an integer variable requires an integer value.

Use something like:

```
 String monthName = determineNameofMonth(monthNumber);
```

(I assume you'll then want to write code to print out monthName, otherwise you're doing nothing with the result of the computation).

Comment: Hi Thanks for that quick answer. But now it says two things: 1. "Variable 'monthNumber' is already defined in the scope:15                                                                                 2. "Variable 'monthNumber' might not have been initialzed:15"

Comment: If you typed what I said ... `String monthName` ... you can't get the errors you say you got.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int monthNumber = scanner.nextInt();
> monthNumber = determineNameofMonth(monthNumber);
> ```

`monthNumber` is a variable. It has been declared to be of type `int` - and that is for the lifetime of that variable (you can't 're-type' a variable in java). That means `monthNumber` is guaranteed to never hold anything that isn't an `int` value, and the compiler will refuse to compile code unless it can be 100% certain that rule holds.

`determineNameofMonth(monthNumber)` is of type `String`, because the method `determineNameofMonth` has been declared as such. `String` is not an int, so, you can't do this.

Presumably you want:

```
String monthName = determineNameofMonth(monthNumber);
```

i.e. make a new variable. The name `monthNumber` shouldn't hold a *name* - then the variable is misnamed.

Note that you don't need to do this stuff, java already has `Month`:

```
import java.time.Month;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type Number for name of month");
    int monthNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    Month m = Month.of(monthNumber);
    System.out.println("You chose: " + m);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the fast help but maybe i should have added some more information. The Task is to work with a switch method  as private static in the main class. So i cant do it like you kindly provided me the code. it now gives me the error: "Variable 'monthNumber' is already defined in the scope" and "Variable 'monthNumber' might not have been initialized"

Comment: Stop trying to call a variable that holds the __name__ of a thing 'monthNumber'. Variable names shouldn't lie. My second snippet, `String monthName = ...;`, that's what you need to be doing.